# service application endpoint failure

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

My eventlogs are flooded with below error.

> A failure was reported when trying to invoke a service application: EndpointFailure
>
> Process Name: w3wp
>   Process ID: 1872
>   AppDomain Name: /LM/W3SVC/707219096/ROOT-1-131623787391610249
>   AppDomain ID: 2
>   Affected Endpoint: http:############ profileservice.svc

I have two app servers, and this end point is hitting one of the app server.

Can anyone please help me to resolve this? Do I need to stop userprofile service on affected Appserver?

> Application: w3wp.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The application requested process termination through System.Environment.FailFast(string message).
>   Message: 
>   Stack:
>      at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String)
>      at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.HelperMethods.HandleShutdown(System.Exception, Boolean)
>      at Microsoft.Office.Server.Diagnostics.FirstChanceHandler.ExceptionFilter(Boolean, TryBlock, FilterBlock, CatchBlock, FinallyBlock)
>      at Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.ExceptionReporting.ReportOnExceptionTag(UInt32, Category, System.String, Boolean, Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.TryBlock, Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.CatchBlock, Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.FinallyBlock)
>      at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.ExcelServerApp..ctor()
>      at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.ExcelServerApp..cctor()
>      at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.ExcelServiceBase.SafeSetContext()
>      at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.ExcelServiceBase.BeginProcessOperation(Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.CommandParameter, Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebMethodBehaviorAttribute, Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebMethodType, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object, Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.Operations.UserOperation)
>      at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.ExcelServiceBase.BeginProcessOperation(Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.CommandParameter, Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebMethodType, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object, Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.Operations.UserOperation)
>      at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.ExcelServiceSoap.BeginGetHealthScore(System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
>      at DynamicClass.AsyncInvokeBeginBeginGetHealthScore(System.Object, System.Object[], System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.AsyncMethodInvoker.InvokeBegin(System.Object, System.Object[], System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
>      at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.ExcelServiceHostFactory+OperationInvokerExceptionWrapper+<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6()
>      at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.ExcelServiceHostFactory+OperationInvokerExceptionWrapper.InvokeHelper(InvokeMethodDelegate, System.Reflection.MethodInfo)
>      at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.ExcelServiceHostFactory+OperationInvokerExceptionWrapper.InvokeBegin(System.Object, System.Object[], System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext, Boolean, System.ServiceModel.OperationContext)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext, System.ServiceModel.OperationContext)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(System.IAsyncResult)
>      at System.Runtime.Fx+AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(System.IAsyncResult)
>      at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1+ReceiveItemAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start()
>      at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler+ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
>      at System.Runtime.Fx+IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
>      at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)

Comment: if you browse the URL (Affted end point), what happen  any error or returning the xml?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP  - it is throwing http 503 error. service not available

Answer (score 0):

If one endpoint is responding upa will work but 2nd should also fixed. I would do try this.

1. From central admin, stop the user profile service on the faulty server then start it again. Now browse the same url from error and see if you get xml. Central admin > system settings > manage services on server...From here from top right down select the faulty server, stop the user profile services.
2. I would also check from faulty server's IIS if services related app pool started...if not start it.

Comment: restart of the service haven't helped.  still same error. The faulty server User Profile Synchronization Service is in stop stage. is this because if this

Comment: sorry, i forgot to verify app pool for this service. it is in stop stage. I started the app pool and now I can see error of XML

Comment: Synchronization services should be running on one server, user profile services can be run on multiple servers. After getting green xml, check event log if you Are getting error?

Comment: again app pool went to stopped stage. not sure why, as the service account for this app pool is in active stage and it is working fine for other App server.  but for this faulty app server, it is always failing.

Comment: Check the event viewer ( under system) you will see why app pool stoped. Also check if service account on the server having log on  as services n log on as batch rights in local srcuirty policy.

Comment: this is the error we are getting. The application requested process termination through System.Environment.FailFast(string message).
and the other error is

Comment: WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/36736776

Comment: can you edit your question with complete detail of error?

Comment: just added "error" to my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72827/discussion-between-waqas-sarwar-mvp-and-raj).